# Opening address stored in cell aaray and the concat the strings

Tags: matlab

Suppose there are five text files. Contents of files are textfile1 = i saw an alligator, textfile2 = alligator was sitting near a tree, textfile3 = alligator was sleeping, textfile4 = parrot was flying, textfile5 = parrot was flying.
I have stored the address for each file in a cell-array. How to open those address and then concatenate the strings to form a single cell-array.

Comment: Have you worked with Matlab before?

Comment: Yes, i have worked. But i can't figure out how to store contents from different textfiles to a single cell array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a cell array called files you could use:

```
txt = cell(0);
for i=1:length(files)
  txt = [txt,fileread(files{i})];
end
```

The cell array `txt` will have the same number of elements as `files` and with each element holding the text from that file.

Comment: Thank you Sir, it was a great help. Solved most of the problem.